# Jetpack Compose - Change color scheme in an exact region of the screen

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Imagine a normal screen with all sorts of components and a circle that can be dragged around. You can consider the circle invisible, but the exact area on which the circle is lying uses a different palette of colors. So, you can say that the circle can be moved around to see what colors lie "underneath" . I'd very much appreciate some ideas on how I could achieve this. Hope I've been clear. If not, please leave a comment.